# Convert Cygwin path to Windows path in a makefile

Tags: makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

How can I convert a Cygwin style path ( `/cygdrive/c/foo/bar` ) to Windows style ( `C:/foo/bar` ) (yes, with / going forward) in a GNU makefile? I have the situation of using Cygwin's make with a GCC that does *not* understand Cygwin style paths, so paths relative to the makefiles location that are produced by make are not accepted by the compiler.

Comment: +1 Good question. I couldn't answer it and just mounted `/` to `\` and had to make my app only from drive c:.

Comment: And how to do vice-versa, convert Win path to Cygwin?

Comment: @dan you can [consider this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51632672/4575793) or just use `cygpath -u "C:/foo/bar"`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the `shell` function to execute the `cygpath` utility with the `-w` flag.

Example:

```
BAR := /cygdrive/c/foo/bar
WIN_BAR := $(shell cygpath -w ${BAR})
```

`cygpath` accepts a lot of additional options. See the man page for details.

Comment: -m for "mixed mode" seems to give me the desired / slashes in the path too.

Comment: Yeah, `-w` seems not to work as make seems to interpret the backslashes as escaping the following character.

Comment: For some reason, every time you give it a relative up-one directory path, cygpath -w converts it into an absolute path.