# Converting Windows path to Unix path in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This question is related to [Convert Cygwin path to Windows path in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400310/convert-cygwin-path-to-windows-path-in-a-makefile)  but it is not the same.

I need to convert a Windows path like:

```
C:\src\bin
```

into a Unix path like:

```
/c/src/bin
```

Inside a makefile, I can use the following code to convert such paths:

```
slashedpath = $(subst \\,\/,$(windowspath))
unixpath = $(shell cygpath -u $(slashedpath))
```

How can I perform the same conversion in a makefile that is being processed by GNU Make, when the *cygpath* function is not available?

p.s.
What if `$(windowspath)` contains multiple paths?  How to convert them all ?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do this? If cygpath is not available do you still have the same mapping of paths in make to the FS? You may only need to fiddle with the slashes to get stuff working.

Comment: Mapping of paths is constant - it can be ignored,  Fiddling with the slashes (prepending a slash and substituting the colon with the drive letter) would be enough, if it can be done with standard GNU make commands.

Comment: Hint: you wouldn't need the inner brackets

Answer (score 0):

The makefile:

```
windowspath=C:\src\bin
unixpath=$(subst \,/,$(subst C:\,/c/,$(windowspath)))
all:
    @echo "$(windowspath)"
    @echo "$(unixpath)"
```

gives the output:

```
C:\src\bin
/c/src/bin
```

This will also work if `$(windowspath)` contains multiple paths. Tested on GNU Make 4.2.1 for *i686-pc-cygwin*, and also on GNU Make 3.81 built for *i686-redhat-linux-gnu*.

I was surprised that this worked.

---

**Update:** This second version will handle various drives such as `C:`, `D:`, etc. Some of these ideas are from Eric Melski's answer to [In GNU Make, how do I convert a variable to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664601/in-gnu-make-how-do-i-convert-a-variable-to-lower-case). If the `Makefile` is:

```
DRIVE = $(subst \
  A:,/a,$(subst B:,/b,$(subst C:,/c,$(subst D:,/d,$(subst \
  E:,/e,$(subst F:,/f,$(subst G:,/g,$(subst H:,/h,$(subst \
  I:,/i,$(subst J:,/j,$(subst K:,/k,$(subst L:,/l,$(subst \
  M:,/m,$(subst N:,/n,$(subst O:,/o,$(subst P:,/p,$(subst \
  Q:,/q,$(subst R:,/r,$(subst S:,/s,$(subst T:,/t,$(subst \
  U:,/u,$(subst V:,/v,$(subst W:,/w,$(subst X:,/x,$(subst \
  Y:,/y,$(subst Z:,/z,$1))))))))))))))))))))))))))

drive = $(subst \
  a:,/a,$(subst b:,/b,$(subst c:,/c,$(subst d:,/d,$(subst \
  e:,/e,$(subst f:,/f,$(subst g:,/g,$(subst h:,/h,$(subst \
  i:,/i,$(subst j:,/j,$(subst k:,/k,$(subst l:,/l,$(subst \
  m:,/m,$(subst n:,/n,$(subst o:,/o,$(subst p:,/p,$(subst \
  q:,/q,$(subst r:,/r,$(subst s:,/s,$(subst t:,/t,$(subst \
  u:,/u,$(subst v:,/v,$(subst w:,/w,$(subst x:,/x,$(subst \
  y:,/y,$(subst z:,/z,$1))))))))))))))))))))))))))

windowspath = c:\src\bin D:\FOO\BAR
unixpath = $(subst \,/,$(call DRIVE,$(call drive,$(windowspath))))

all:
    @echo Original: "$(windowspath)"
    @echo Modified: "$(unixpath)"
```

then the output to `make` is:

```
Original: c:\src\bin D:\FOO\BAR
Modified: /c/src/bin /d/FOO/BAR
```

---

**Update 2:** The most straight-forward approach, and the most flexible, is to use a standard regular-expression handler such as `perl` or `sed`, if these are available. For example, with GNU sed, this Makefile will work as required:

```
windowspath = c:\src\bin D:\FOO\BAR
unixpath = $(shell echo '$(windowspath)' | \
           sed -E 's_\<(.):_/\l\1_g; s_\\_/_g')

all:
    @echo Original: "$(windowspath)"
    @echo Modified: "$(unixpath)"
```

Explanation of `sed`:

- `s_\<(.):_/\l\1_g` For every word starting with something like `A:` or `a:`, replace the start with `/a`.
- `s_\\_/_g` Replace all backslashes with forward slashes.

Comment: @shu: Everything here is in `GNU Make` syntax.

Comment: There is a much more elegant solution than Update2: `unixpath=/$(subst \,/,$(subst :\,/,$(windowspath)))`. This puts a `/` in front and just replaces `:\` by `/` first. A general rule of thumb for every programmer: copy-pasting produces bad code. Use generic code containing functions or subroutines, and templates if available, instead.

Comment: If you're using Cygwin or Git Bash, as opposed to an actual Unix system, perhaps the %SYSTEMDRIVE% environment variable ($SYSTEMDRIVE in Cygwin etc.) could be used to avoid the need for Update 2?

Comment: Does anyone know how to edit this question to have the indented makefile lines start with hard tabs instead of rows of spaces? I tried making the edit and replacing them, but even with hard tabs used in the markdown source the end result is still the same.